# Повтор предлогов

Tags: стилистика

Давно интересует вопрос, когда предлоги повторяются при перечислении, а когда - нет.

Например: "Эти ценности переданы ему ДЛЯ хранения или ДЛЯ других целей", "Ценности получены им ПО доверенности или ПО другим документам".

Думаю, здесь повтор предлога не нужен. Но ведь бывают случаи, когда он нужен. Может, подскажете конкретное правило, если такое есть?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько знаю, грамматических правил на этот счет нет. Так что руководствоваться приходится стилистикой и здравым смыслом, а это вещи довольно субъективные. Я так понимаю, что предлог всегда лучше повторить, если только пречисляемое не является единыным целым. Типа "подарки для жениха и невесты". "Для жениха и для невесты" обзначало бы нечто другое.

А так, думаю, что если члены перечисления отстоят друг от друга (т.е. усложнены каким-то обособленными оборотами и распространённым описанием), то предлог необходим: "Эти ценности переданы ему ДЛЯ хранения в банковской ячейке или другом защищенном месте или ДЛЯ других целей" (над смыслом не заморачивайтесь, с потолка вязто). Тут без второго ДЛЯ - никак.